# Different elevation values between using rasterio, xarray, rioxarray, gdal and QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, rasterio, rioxarray, xarray

I am trying to extract elevation values from a DEM raster under array format by using some packages (rasterio, xarray, rioxarray, and gdal). However, they seemed to give me a different results from what I observed in QGIS. For example, with below attached raster file:

If I use those packages to read the elevations under array:

- Using rasterio:

```
file = rasterio.open("example.nc")
array = file.read(1)
print(array[13, 11])
```

- Using xarray:

```
file = xarray.open_dataset("example.nc")
array = file.idw.values[0].[::-1]
print(array[13, 11])
```

- Using rioxarray

```
file = rioxarray.open_rasterio("example.nc")
array = file.values[0]
print(array[13, 11])
```

- Using gdal:

```
file = gdal.Open("example.nc")
array = file.ReadAsArray()
print(array[13, 11])
```

They all gave the same values:

```
528.6458436408917
```

However, when I use ['Value Tool Plugin'](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/) in QGIS with the same row and column (13, 11), it gave me a different result of 528.64587.

[image: qgis screenshot of value tool showing value of 528.64587]

The example file is here https://ufile.io/jrq0rzju (Free Download --> Slow download)

Why does this happen?

Comment: Where in QGIS can I find the Value tool?

Comment: [QGIS plugin Value Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/)

Comment: Try to contact the author of the plugin. The normal QGIS query tool (Identify features, little i as an icon) shows also value 528.6458436408917 for that pixel.

Comment: And what's the real meaning of a difference of 0.00003 m between values while the accuracy of the DEM is much lower ? All values equal 528 m ([Demystifying Floating Point Precision](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/11/21/floating-point-precision/), [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html))

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers